# How to directly execute cmake script without -P?

Tags: cmake

I know `-P` is used to execute a cmake script file. But I don't want create a file for a simple logic. I want to execute statement like this:

> cmake "if(foo) do_something endif()"

The reason I want this feature is that I want to use if/else in `add_custom_target` and `add_custom_command` to execute some command according to whether a **CMAKE variable** is defined.

Comment: I'm not sure, that C is suitable for your case. You can write your `if` statement in bash

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot execute CMake code directly in the `add_custom_command`, and this would have a little sence. "I want ...  to execute some command according to whether a variable is defined." - What kind of this variable? If this is a **CMake variable**, defined in the current script, you should put `if` around the `add_custom_command` call, not inside it. If this is an *environment variable*, you may process it with a shell script.

Comment: @Tsyvarev But If I put `if` around the `add_custom_command`,  things will go bad when cmake cache the variable which I gave last time. So the command is still executed unless I clean the cache beforehand. But, If I put `if` inside it, the command is executed only when I explicitly issue `make target` and the variable condition meets.

Comment: "Normal" setting of *CACHE* variable is done via `cmake -D..` invocation (or in CMake GUI hitting "Configuration"). In both cases the project will be reconfigured and `add_custom_command` invocation will be recalculated.

Comment: I may not give `-D` every time. Just do it when I plan to create new images.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a good solution to this. Now describe as follows.

Let's say I want to add two targets, whose aim are to create docker images and upload to remote repository when issuing `make images` and `make publish`. I use `VERSION` , `GIT_COMMIT` and `PATCH` to compose an image tag. `GIT_COMMIT` can be obtained from `git log` by using `execute_process`, and I need to pass newer `VERSION` and `PATCH` from command line every time I want to create images. (But if I don't plan to create, they won't be given)

So the complete statements are like this:

```
execute_process(COMMAND git log --pretty=format:%h -n 1 OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT) 

set(DOCKER_CERBERUS_URL "docker-registry.com/db/cerberus:${VERSION}-${GIT_COMMIT}.${PATCH}")

add_custom_target(images
    COMMENT "Creating docker images ..."
    # clean the cache
    COMMAND rm -f CMakeCache.txt # important !

    # if VERSION and PATCH are not given, don't build it
    COMMAND /bin/sh -c "if [ x${VERSION} != x -a x${PATCH} != x ]; then docker build -t ${DOCKER_CERBERUS_URL} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/docker/; fi"
    DEPENDS cerberus
    VERBATIM )

add_custom_target(publish
    COMMENT "Uploading images ..."
    COMMAND docker push ${DOCKER_CERBERUS_URL}
    DEPENDS images )
```

Then every time I want to create or publish with newer version number and patch number, I use `cmake .. -DVERSION=xxx -DPATCH=xxx`, `make images` or `make publish`.

There's something which may be strange. When I first issue `cmake .. -DVERSION=xxx -DPATCH=xxx`, then `make images`, `sh command` will be executed. Then I issue `make images` again, `sh command` will not be executed. My guess is: in the first run of `make images`, cmake will first load variable from `CMakeCache.txt` into memory, then `sh command` can get variables's value from memory, and at this time `CMakeCache.txt` has been deleted. So in the second run, the variables have no value.

Comment: This approach seems to have the same results as wrapping `add_custom_target` call with `if(VERSION AND PATCH)`. There is a little reason to program shell script if you can check that within `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Acutally If `if(VERSION AND PATCH` is used, I think cache needs to be cleaned beforehand manually or programatically, since the variables in cache is no longer new. But I don't want it to be cleaned every time I run cmake, and I won't run cmake always with `-DVERSION=xxx -DPATCH=xxx`. Just clean the cache only when I issue `make images` or `make publish`. Seems that putting `if` around `add_custom_target` cannot reach my goal

Comment: Oh, you manually clear CMake cache within `add_custom_target`. But your guessing that CMake loads `VERSION` and `PATCH` variables only when you run `make images` is **wrong**: these variables are **already substituted** after *configuration* stage (`cmake` invocation). When you run `make images` the second time, CMake detects absence of `CMakeCache.txt` file, and **re-runs configuration automatically**, thus updating the command line for `images` target. You may detect reconfiguration step by closer inspection of output during `make images`.